# How do I format a Temporal PlainDateTime?

Tags: javascript, datetime-format, temporal

Is it possible to format a Temporal.PlainDateTime yet?

```
const f = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-us", {
    hour: "2-digit",
    minute: "2-digit",
})
const t = Temporal.Now.plainDateTimeISO().add({ 'nanoseconds': 10000000 })
const str = f.format(t)
```

Comment: no, though there is a (non-production)[polyfill](https://github.com/js-temporal/temporal-polyfill#readme)

Comment: Please don't tag your titles. See [ask].

Comment: According to [the proposed spec](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/plaindatetime.html#toLocaleString), the `.toLocaleString(locale, options)` method's options parameter is the same as for `Intl.DateTimeFormat`'s options. It is also likely that it will eventually be accepted by the `DateTimeFormat.format()` method. However, it is still a VERY EARLY spec that is [not supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=temporal) by any browser or server yet.